# Tableview crashes when I scroll up to the top and hold

Tags: uitableview, xcode5

I have a table view that is fed by core data. It works fine except when I scroll back to the top and hold it there. Then the app crashes.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

// The Model for this class.
//
// When it gets set, we create an NSFetchRequest to get all Photographers in the database associated with it.
// Then we hook that NSFetchRequest up to the table view using an NSFetchedResultsController.

```
- (void)setManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    _managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext) {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"TestResults"];
        request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
        request.predicate = nil; // all records

        self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    } else {
        self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    }
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

// Uses NSFetchedResultsController's objectAtIndexPath: to find the Photographer for this row in the table.
// Then uses that Photographer to set the cell up.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TestResults"];

    TestResults *testResult = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self showTestResult:testResult];


    // show traffic light color


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy hh:mm a"];
    NSString *theDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:testResult.date];

    cell.textLabel.text = theDate;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = testResult.overallPassOrFail;

    NSLog(@"overall: %@", testResult.overallPassOrFail);
    NSLog(@"light color: %@", testResult.trafficLightColor);

    // retrieve an image
    if ([testResult.trafficLightColor isEqualToString:@"Red"]) {
        self.lightImage = @"Red_Light";
    } else if ([testResult.trafficLightColor isEqualToString:@"Yellow"]) {
        self.lightImage = @"Yellow_Light";
    } else {
        self.lightImage = @"Green_Light";
    }
    NSString *imagefile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.lightImage ofType:@"png"];
    self.imageOne = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagefile];
    cell.imageView.image = self.imageOne;
    //

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: id like to see your code or what are the sent log messages??

Comment: Here's the error;2014-02-07 11:38:32.193 Me Myself[1057:70b] -[HistoryViewController refresh]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb6b16a0
2014-02-07 11:38:32.202 Me Myself[1057:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HistoryViewController refresh]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb6b16a0'

Comment: ok, now i would like to see your code... it seems like a code error...

Comment: Here's the code. I borrowed it from the Stanford ios class.  It only crashed when I swipe my finger down to scroll the table and the pinwheel spins at the top then it crashes. thanks for the help.

Comment: I need to see the code where you are calling a method called refresh

Comment: Ok. here it is. I commented this out and it seems to work okay now, except the pinwheel spins.- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
//    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self
//                            action:@selector(refresh)
//                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

Comment: Then yeap, thats the problem... you have no refresh method implemented... then what have you assigned as refreshContrl?

Comment: nothing. that code came from somewhere else and I commented it out. The hazard of repurposing old code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ure welcome, so could you mark my answer as the correct one?? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a method that is not implemented, check your code ;)